# Как ввести последовательность символов и посчитать сумму нечетных чисел?

Tags: c#

Как решить следующую задачу: В консоль вводится последовательность символов. Выполнить сложение всех
нечетных чисел если таковые присутствуют и вывести в консоль. При вводе
символов не входящих во множество символов-цифр завершить работу
программы.

пытался сделать следующим способом, но не получилось:

```
int oddNumberSum = 0;

            string number = Console.ReadLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < number.Length; i++)
            {
                if (number[i] >= '0' && number[i] <= '9')
                {
                    int[] array = number.Select(x => (int)char.GetNumericValue(x)).ToArray();

                    for (int index = 0; index < array.Length; index++)
                    {
                        
                        if (array[index] % 2 != 0)
                        {
                            oddNumberSum += array[index];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Сумма нечетных чисел: {oddNumberSum}");
            Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возьми лист бумаги с карандашом и пройдись по своему алгоритму. Он у тебя считает северное сияние. Или научись пользоваться отладчиком.

Comment: Зачем Вам второй for? Зачем Вам array? Внутри первого if достаточно провести проверку на четность приведённого к int символа и сложить его с результатом, если проверка прошла нужным образом. Вы или перемудрили или не понимаете, что делаете...

Comment: `if (number[i] % 2 != 0){oddNumberSum = number[i] + number[i]}`  додумался до этого только. Вы правы я не понимаю что делаю, поэтому может предложите свой вариант кода?

Answer (score 0):

Через System.Linq:

```
Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine().ToList().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).Where(x => x % 2 == 1).Sum());
```

Развёрнутый алгоритм:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

string[] inputStrNums = input.ToList().Select(x => x.ToString());
int[] inputNums = new int[inputStrNums.Length];

for(int i = 0; i < inputStrNums.Length; i++)
   inputNums[i] = int.Parse(inputStrNums[i]);

int outputNum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < inputNums.Length; i++)
   if(inputNums[i] % 2 == 1)
      outputNum += inputNums[i];

Console.WriteLine(outputNum);
```